# Android studio , Isnt this the correct way of retrieving a string from shared preferences and casting it to a hashset<string>?

Tags: java, android, casting, sharedpreferences

My code is:

```
HashSet<String> set = (HashSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes" , null);
```

I got that exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.S

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Set
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getStringSet(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:293)
        at com.example.notes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
```

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot*, under any circumstances, cast a `String` to a `Set` (or anything but a type that `String` directly implements, such as `Object`, `Comparable`, or `Serializable`).

You must explicitly write code to *convert* the `String` to a `Set`, such as (for example) splitting it on comma characters and adding each element of the split to a set you create.

Comment: doesnt sharedpreferences.getStringSet() return a set of strings, im trying to cast that to a hashset of strings, not a string by itself. i saw this in a tutorial and it worked , but its not working for me.

Comment: Well, the documentation specifies that `getStringSet` will throw a `ClassCastException` if there is a preference with that name that isn't actually a set.  It looks like you have a preference with that name that's actually a string, not a set of strings.